# "Бабник" для квітів

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми

Нещодавно відвідав одне місто на Галичині. Якось мене попросили підлити квіти у "**бабнику**" (виглядає як звичайний горщик для квітів). Цікавить чи взагалі зустрічається це слово у такому значенні в українській мові? І чи є якась різниця між "бабником" і "горщиком для квітів"?

А ще цікаво те, що я не зміг його знайти ні в СУМі, ні в [Словнику галицького діалекту](http://www.aratta-ukraine.com/text_ua.php?id=2291).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ВТССУМ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53393/826954.html)

> бабник  I б`абник-а, ч.  Те саме, що бабій 1), баболюб.
>
> **II бабн`ик
>   -а, ч.  Посудина, у якій випікають бабу III.**
>
> [Баба](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53393/826901.html) III -и, ж.  Рід печива з пшеничного борошна.
>
> [Горщок](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53395/855311.html) горшка, ч. Глиняний посуд, у якому варять їжу.
>
> **|| Глиняний посуд із діркою у дні для вирощування квітів та інших рослин.**

На жаль зображення "бабника" в значенні посуду не знайшла, тому сказати точно чи є різниця між цими посудинами не можу. Якщо суто з означень наведених в ВТССУМ то горщик для квітів з диркою у дні, а бабник ні.